# Promise do Javascript Com Erro de Execução

Tags: javascript, promises

Estou tentando resolver o seguinte exercício: 
Crie uma tela com um  que deve receber o nome de um usuário no Github. Após digitar o
nome do usuário e clicar no botão buscar. A aplicação deve buscar pela API do Github (conforme
URL abaixo) os dados de repositórios do usuário e mostrá-los em tela:
URL de exemplo: https://api.github.com/users/diego3g/repos
Basta alterar "diego3g" pelo nome do usuário. Depois de preencher o input e adicionar, as informações devem preencher uma lista.

Não consigo entender o porque de rodar antes de eu clicar no enviar e ainda ir direto para o .catch.

Agradeço toda a ajuda!

```js
var lista = " "; 
var linha = " ";
var perfil = " ";
var textoLinha = " ";

var minhaPromise = function(){    
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var x = document.getElementById("user").value;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", 'https://api.github.com/users/'+x+'/repos');
        xhr.send('null');

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(xhr.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr.status === 200){                       
                    resolve();                    
               } else {
                   reject();
                  
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

minhaPromise() 
    .then(function() {
            lista = document.querySelector('#corpo ul');  
            perfil = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText) || [];for(var dados of perfil){
                linha = document.createElement('li');
                textoLinha =  document.createTextNode(Object.values(dados));
                linha.appendChild(textoLinha);
                lista.appendChild(linha);  
           } 
           })   
        
    .catch(function(){
        lista = document.querySelector('#corpo ul');                 linha = document.createElement('li');
        textoLinha = document.createTextNode("Não encontrado.");
        linha.appendChild(textoLinha);
        lista.appendChild(linha); 
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="desafio2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="corpo">
            <input type="text" name="nome" id="user" />
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar"  onclick="minhaPromise()" />
            <ul></ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Não consigo entender o porque de rodar antes de eu clicar

É simples... olhe bem para o código que escreveu:

- criou uma funcao chamada `minhaPromise`
- mas a seguir, está a chamar essa funcao com `minhaPromise()`

*mas tem mais :)*

- se por alguma razao o `xhr.readyState` não for `4` nunca resolvera nada
- a sua promessa [deve de passar os dados que recebeu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) `resolve(xhr.responseText)`
- a sua rejeicao [deve passar um novo object `Error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject): `reject(new Error('texto a passar'))`
- e um erro é chamar uma funcao asyncrona em `onclick="minhaPromise()"`

para resolver o seu problema, tem apenas de mudar um pouco o codigo:

- resolva e rejeite correctamente

```js
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    return xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200
        ? resolve(xhr.responseText)
        : reject(new Error('Something off!'))
}
```

- envolva a chamada `minhaPromise()` numa funcao, para que possa ser executada, apenas quando queremos

```js
var onButtonClick = function() {
    minhaPromise()
        .then(function(data) { 
            // "data" é o objecto com o texto do request
            // perfil = JSON.parse(data) || [];
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            // "err.message" contem "Something off!"
        })
}
```

- no botao, chame essa nova funcao (e nao use submit`pois nao tem qualquer`form`, um botao normal é suficiente)

```html
<button onclick="onButtonClick()">Enviar</button>
```

---

já deixei de usar o `XMLHttpRequest` a algum tempo, desde então uso o [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) e se quiser ver o seu projecto a funcionar, com as alteracoes que expecifiquei, [pode ver no CodePen](https://codepen.io/balexandre/pen/dyorjVy?editors=1010)